# Statistical measures for variable selection?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python, categorical-data, many-categories

I have a data set which has multiple features (26) of high cardinality (categorical), low cardinality (categorical), numerical type.

I wanted to select features for the target (numerical) prediction. I want to carry some statistical analysis for this purpose. So far I carried P value, Anova - F value in Python. P value was done by target encoding the categorical features. What more statistical analysis can I do for filtering features or get insight of data.

Comment: Maybe it is just due to my ignorance or lack of knowledge but all the statistical test for doing this do (according to my personal point of view) suffer from two drawbacks: First of all they only work under assumptions that are sometimes difficult to explain/to check. Secondly the result has to be interpreted (p-hacking). In these situations I usually proceed like this: compute a model that offers feature importance (for example a random forest). Do a cross validation in order to assess that the model is reasonable and then check whether the feature importance makes sense from a businessPOV

Comment: I appreciate your effort! I am actually just on your way. As far now I did this on random forest and also got feature importance, but problem is even R.F is just taking one or two variables into account and more importantly its not predicting well on test set. I am not satisfied. Maybe I am unable to use the strength of R.F  efficiently. Would you like to add add something to this?

Comment: As an addition to that for high categorical features , I used target mean encoding. I thought maybe there is something inefficient in that , so I took ANOVA approach

Comment: First of all I have a question: What do you actually mean when you say 'target mean encoding'? Does it mean that for a value v of a categorical column X you compute the mean of the target variable over all rows that have v in X and then use this as a substitution for v, is that correct? Do you do this before or after you split into train and test? Also what hyperparameters did you use for RF? Usually you cannot get the best possible result with tuning hyperparameters (but with smart feature engineering) but you can bad ones if you use the wrong hyperparameters...

Comment: Also I think you should invest more why exactly RF is not working well: Sort the test set (with prediction) by the error that the model makes and investigate by eye (i.e. single cases with highest error) and by drawing some graphs that attempt to explain why the error is high... for example, you could draw a boxplot of the error and the x-axis are all the values of a categorical column... in this way you can see whether the model has isues with single values

Comment: Ok, yes I did the mean encoding in the way you interpreted. But I now realised , I should have done it only for train set and then map that value in the test . So far I did for the whole set at once. I correct this now. But definitely your inputs on smart feature engineering and error box plots has widen my thinking , I thank you for that. Can I know techniques behind smart feature engineering if there are any?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104454/discussion-between-chinti-and-fabian-werner).

Answer (score 0):

You may select features considering the importance of the features for out of sample prediction. I suggest two very interesting and general methods that you can use:

1) [Permutation importance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/permutation_importance.html): The permutation feature importance is defined to be the decrease in a model score when a single feature value is randomly shuffled

2) [Shap values](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/11/shapley-value-machine-learning-interpretability-game-theory/): It is not an easy concept since it is based in game theory, but it shows the importance of each feature.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. I will take look into both techniques. I have a question though, is it necessary for the categorical features to be numerical encoded or categorical features can be kept as it is for these techniques. Thank you

Comment: In the end, you will not be selecting categorical variables. The first step is to convert the categorical variables to dummy variables. Then the methods treat the dummies separately. For instance, imagine that you have a categorical variable related to size with three possible values: small, medium and big. This categorical variable can be converted to two dummies, the other effect is in the constant. Consider the dummies are associated with medium and big. The methods will give the importance of the two dummies separately. One of them can be very important and the other not too important...